# Error when trying to generate FFmpeg thumbnails with .webp

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, fluent-ffmpeg

I was trying to export webp thumbnails from my video but i got an error that the `Default encoder for format webp (codec webp) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.`

This is my code

```
  ffmpeg()
      .input(videoInput)
      .screenshot({
        count: 5,
        folder: outDir,
        filename: "thumbnail-%i.webp"
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Thumbnail exporting finished!');
        return res()
      })
      .on('start', (stdout) => {
        console.log(stdout);
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error in generating thumbnails:', err.message);
        return rej(err)
      })
```

I was expecting to have thumbnails but an error happens

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 0.8722221666666666 -i /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56-baity-intro.mp4 -y -filter_complex split=5[screen0][screen1][screen2][screen3][screen4] -vframes 1 -map [screen0] /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/thumbnail-1.webp -vframes 1 -map [screen1] -ss 0.8722221666666666 /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/thumbnail-2.webp -vframes 1 -map [screen2] -ss 1.7444443333333335 /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/thumbnail-3.webp -vframes 1 -map [screen3] -ss 2.6166665 /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/thumbnail-4.webp -vframes 1 -map [screen4] -ss 3.4888886666666674 /var/folders/tk/4cc2j1r97tn36yc4zytl6xdr0000gn/T/temp-dir-55738-M4xzH9y06CGs/3dbedb5a-8a70-4199-a225-e0c973bd7f56/thumbnail-5.webp
Error in generating thumbnails: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format webp (codec webp) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format webp (codec webp) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is a simple example of getting a frame of video

```
ffmpeg(filePath)
.seekInput(1)
.frames(1)
.output(thumbnailPath)
.on('error', err => done(err))
.on('end', () => done())
.run();
```